# Hissing sound from one of the Creative BlasterX Kratos speakers

Tags: audio, speakers

I recently bought new speakers from Creative, the Sound BlasterX Kratos S3. I don't need outstanding sound as I'm using the speakers sparsely anyway but the problem I encountered is that the left speaker keeps hissing regardless of whether something is played and the volume/bass knobs position.

I did my research and some people are complaining that their Creatives are giving out a slight hiss too - and my right speaker does that too but I'd be completely fine with it were it not for the left speaker which hisses thrice as loud. I recorded a video to show this in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar00qWZ_pN0

I've tried connecting them to a different audio source, tried moving the cable that goes to the left speaker away from any other cables to make sure a nearby power cable isn't causing the disturbance somewhere along the way but to no avail. As I mentioned, the volume and bass knobs make no difference either and the hissing is always of consistent intensity. Tried installing Creative's drivers from the website and their BlasterX Acoustic Engine software but it changed nothing either.

I'm pretty desperate for a solution different than sending them in for warranty cause where I live the warranty laws are a nightmare and will surely mean months of back-and-forth between me and the seller for which I don't really have energy right now. Anything else I may try to combat such an issue?

EDIT: As per the comments and my further research, I did try to troubleshoot some more -  I tried plugging it into a different socket but to no avail. Swapping the channels does not help either. If I disconnect them from the computer, they both start buzzing loudly (and get even louder if I for example touch the jack with my finger).

And regardless of input and whether the channels are swapped, the left speaker is the one always hissing. Did not have the chance to try the ferite torriodal yet.

Comment: You could try to loop the problematic speaker cable a couple of times through a ferite torriodal transformer core and see if it suppresses the hiss. You can also find these on old USB cables that would do the same thing, https://www.ebay.com/i/372434066491?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=372434066491&targetid=884307440789&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9007368&poi=&campaignid=9344508184&mkgroupid=94993822459&rlsatarget=pla-884307440789&abcId=1139336&merchantid=101653345&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoICW6qK06QIVEkWGCh1vPQE4EAQYAyABEgKGgPD_BwE

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - hiss [pure white noise] doesn't come from EM interference, it comes from poor amp circuits. It's generated long before the speaker cable, which is at far too high a voltage to suffer any kind of simple EMI. Quick test; unplug the system from the computer [being careful not to ground the plug] then check again. If it still hisses, it's entirely the amp's issue. Return it.

Comment: @tetsujin, not enough info for either of our comments to **not** be conjecture. That method worked for me with a poopy set of altec lansing speakers with the bassbox amplifier. But there are many many things that could cause this. Including a ground loop in the A.C circuit it's attached to...https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techhive.com/article/3063590/how-to-get-rid-of-hum-and-eliminate-other-noises-from-your-audio-and-video-systems.amp.html

Comment: A pure sine wave ups (that has an isolation transformer) would stop this **if** it's a ground loop.

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question suggests it is EMI or grounding. Nothing in your linked article will cure hiss; in fact in my brief skim of it, the only time it's mentioned is 'when you turn your amp up' & says 'you can't fix that'.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did try plugging it into a different socket but to no avail. Swapping the channels does not help either. If I disconnect them from the computer, they both start buzzing loudly (and get even louder if I for example touch the jack with my finger).

And regardless of input and whether the channels are swapped, the left speaker is the one always hissing. Did not have the chance to try the ferite torriodal yet.